# 8 years ago; still valid? Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, code-injection

I'm starting fresh here and reading a lot of posts on injection.  This one is excellent but it's 8 years old.  Is it still valid?  php/pdo/mysql is changing all the time.  Thanks.

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection?rq=1)

Comment: Yes. PDO and mysqli_* functions are still your best bet for avoiding sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JNevill that is, `mysqli_*` _with prepared statements (when necessary)_ :P

Answer (score 1):

The highest-rated answers there still very much apply.
In general, however, beware, of anyone who tells you that a certain method of preventing a certain security issue is a 100% cure. In this case, especially be careful with dynamic SQL. I would actually avoid using dynamic queries altogether if you're just getting started.